# How can I secure folder access to the user in windows using python

Tags: python, directory, locking

Actually I want that user will not able to access folder, and images which I stores into folder even not able to open that folder. I am using windows operating system. And I want to do it using python, I tried a lot but can't find solution.Can anyone help me .
Thank you in advance

Comment: You can either encrypt the data so that the user can't read it (at least it can make it hard to find the key for decryption) or your program can get administrator rights to forbid read access to the folder for normal users (but not administrators). Apart from that it is not possible except with system software which would behave similar to malware.

Answer (score 0):

Setting folder permission

You want the `win32security` module, which is a part of [pywin32](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/). Here's an [Example](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/add-security-to-a-file.html) of doing the sort of thing you want to do :

```
import win32security
import ntsecuritycon as con

FILENAME = "whatever"

userx, domain, type = win32security.LookupAccountName ("", "User X")
usery, domain, type = win32security.LookupAccountName ("", "User Y")

sd = win32security.GetFileSecurity(FILENAME, 
win32security.DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION)
dacl = sd.GetSecurityDescriptorDacl()   # instead of dacl = 
win32security.ACL()

dacl.AddAccessAllowedAce(win32security.ACL_REVISION, con.FILE_GENERIC_READ | 
con.FILE_GENERIC_WRITE, userx)
dacl.AddAccessAllowedAce(win32security.ACL_REVISION, con.FILE_ALL_ACCESS, usery)

sd.SetSecurityDescriptorDacl(1, dacl, 0)   # may not be necessary
win32security.SetFileSecurity(FILENAME, 
win32security.DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, sd)
```